# Spherical and Cartesian forms of divergence

Tags: electric-fields, vectors, differentiation, calculus

Suppose the electric field found in some region is $$\overrightarrow{E} = ar^3\vec{e}_r$$ in coordinates
spherical (a is a constant). What is the charge density?

So, using the spherical form of differential form of Gauss Law:

$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2E_r) = 5ar^2$$

But, I tried to do

$$\vec{e}_r = x\hat i + y\hat j + z\hat k \\
r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\ 
\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E = \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 6ar^3
$$

Why does the second method give a incorrect answer?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already see from the units that the first expression must be the wrong one. The radial part $E_r$ of the electric field is given by the scalar product $E_r=\vec E\cdot\vec{e}_r$, therefore without other angular components, we have $\vec{E}=E_r\vec{e}_r$, not $\vec{E}=E_r\vec{r}$, and therefore $E_r=ar^4$, not $E_r=ar^3$. This is a common mistake. The divergence then becomes the same as in the second equation:
$$\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E
=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm d(E_rr^2)}{\mathrm dr}
=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\mathrm d(ar^6)}{\mathrm dr}
=\frac{1}{r^2}\cdot 6ar^5
=6ar^3.$$
**EDIT** after the electric field changed from $\vec E=ar^3\vec{r}$ to $\vec E=ar^3\vec{e}_r$, which made the first equation in the question
now correct and the second now wrong:

Using the chain rule, we have:
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^2
=\frac{x}{r}
\Rightarrow
\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}
=2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}
=2x$$
(analogous with $y$ and $z$) and therefore using the product rule, we have:
\begin{align*}
\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E
&=\frac{\partial(ar^2x)}{\partial x}
+\frac{\partial(ar^2y)}{\partial y}
+\frac{\partial(ar^2z)}{\partial z}
=ar^2+ax\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}
+ar^2+ax\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial y}
+ar^2+ax\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial z} \\
&=3ar^2+2a(x^2+y^2+z^2)
=5ar^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the first expression in a wrong way. Now my question makes sense.

Comment: I added that accordingly.

Comment: Because $\vec r=(x,y,z)$ and not $\vec e_r=(x,y,z)$ (as it's the normed radial vector). Therefore if given $\vec E=ar^3\vec e_r=ar^2\vec r$, then $E_x=ar^2x$, usw.